# AMD Radeon Driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm a complete rookie with Ubuntu, I'm exploring it for hours.

My question is: I saw "AMD drivers are no longer supported on Ubuntu".

**Is any possibility to run better graphics in my OS, or other similar?**

Anyways, I'm searching for a possible solution.

Here is my benchmark:

> Processor     : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz Memory        : 12223MB
>   (1986MB used) Machine Type        : Desktop Operating System      : Ubuntu
>   18.04.4 LTS
>
> -Display- Resolution      : 1920x1080 pixels OpenGL Renderer      : **Radeon RX 570 Series** (POLARIS10, DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-41-generic, LLVM 9.0.1) X11
>   Vendor        : The X.Org Foundation
>
> -Mother Board- Vendor     : ASUSTeK Computer INC. Version     : System Version
>   -BIOS- Date       : 01/08/2014 Vendor     : American Megatrends Inc.  Version     : 0904

**Thank you in advance :)**

PS: Any BIOS configuration recommendations?

Comment: I don't know your video card, but providing the source for your invalid statement "AMD drivers are no longer supported on Ubuntu" maybe helpful.  AMD themselves helped improve some drivers before AMD decided agreed to end some driver products but had you provided your source we may have provided more accurate responses, maybe https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD will be useful, but AMD does still make Linux & drivers (Ubuntu uses those drivers).

Comment: @guiverc I saw the info here: https://i.postimg.cc/rsfDrYnH/Screenshot-at-2020-03-01-06-52-42.png

Comment: Yes and that also mentions *the open source drivers you are currently using will deliver the most stable performance out of your card* as AMD themselves helped improve the open source drivers as the intended replacement. I've provided the best link already that I'm aware of.

Comment: That link is very wide, I don't know how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

The open source AMD drivers (default option in Ubuntu) is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a complete overview of possibilities here:
https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation

The official AMD driver for Ubunto 20.04 is not released yet. So yes, for now the open source drivers are the best option.

With a little bit of a hack, you can install OpenCL support:
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~sarunas/amdgpu.html